# Как выделить память для двумерного массива?Си

Tags: c, память

Мне нужно создать массив забитый 1 и 0.Как можно выделить память под случайный двумерный массив?Постоянно сталкиваюсь со странным выводом

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int MemoryAccess(int I,int J){
   int *MEM;
   MEM = (int*)calloc((I*J),sizeof(int));
   int A[I][J];
   srand(time(NULL)); 
 
    for(int i=0;i<I;i++){ 
 
    printf("\n"); 
 
        for(int j=0;j<J;j++){ 
 
            A[I][J]= 0 + rand()%1 +MEM; 
 
        } 
 
    }
    for(int i=0;i<I;i++){ 
 
     printf("\n"); 
 
        for(int j=0;j<J;j++){
          printf("%d\n",A[I][J]);

}
      }
  }

int main() {
    int I=5,J=15,*P;
    P = MemoryAccess(I,J);
    
}
```

Output

```
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
10445409
```

Comment: вы путаете везде Размеры массива и индексы. `printf("%d\n",A[I][J]);` => `printf("%d\n",A[i][j]);`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Добрый день,поменял,но все равно выводит непонятный результат

Comment: вы присваиваете адрес памяти `A[I][J]= MEM;`. Задача была совсем в другом. `A[i][j]=rand()%2;`